# I need to know via MWS API the amazon fees of each transaction for sales done by FBA and by merchant

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

Is there any way to see the exact fee Amazon takes?. I´ve tried using the reports API and using the fee calculator but all I can find is an estimate. What is the best way to do this?